# Is there a way pairplots could include 'Objects' dtypes variables?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is the part of my dataframe:

`Category  Calories Total Fat Saturated Fat  Trans Fat
0   Breakfast   300  13.0       5.0             0.0
1   Breakfast   250  8.0        3.0             0.0
2   Breakfast   370  23.0       8.0             0.0
3   Breakfast   450  28.0      10.0             0.0
4   Breakfast   400  23.0       8.0             0.0`

I want to use `sns.pairplot()` func. however, it won't show me 'Category'. Let me know if there some way to add 'Category' variable on to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `pairplots`, categorical variables can be used to set `hues` but not co construct any of the facets of the `FacetGrid`. See for example this code from the `seaborn` manual: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

```python
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
```

```
In[280]: iris.dtypes
Out[280]: 
sepal_length    float64
sepal_width     float64
petal_length    float64
petal_width     float64
species          object
dtype: object
```

you can see that if you launch

```python
g = sns.pairplot(iris)
```

there is no facet showing the `species` variable. However if you now do

```python
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species")
```

here come your data nicely colored according to the `species`
[image: pairplot with hue set to species]

#### added

You may force your categorical variable to be in one of the facets by spcifying it in the `varslist`

```python
g = sns.pairplot(iris, vars=['petal_length', 'species'])
```

leads you to something that was not perhaps the original intent of `pairplots` but may be what you are looking for

[image: a pairplot containing a categorical variable]

Comment: Not the hue. Is there a way I can add the 'species' in your data set to the one row and the column?

Comment: Based on the `pairplot` specifications, you might pass a `varslist` of variable names (optional):

    "Variables within data to use, otherwise use every column with a _numeric_ datatype."

Comment: You may _force_ your categorical variable to be in the facets. Try this: `g = sns.pairplot(iris, vars=['petal_length', 'species'])` and check whether  you like the output that you get.

Comment: It's actually quite useful to have categorical variables in that representation along with numeric. Similar functions in R do that by default.